# Primefaces file upload several times problem

Tags: primefaces

I have form, where is a button for add a small outputpanel. Outputpanel have a button to choose file and next button for upload file. The user can add few outputpanels. But when I add second or more output panel the file upload starts behave strangely. When I want to upload file to first outputpanel, I choose file, and if i clicked to upload app write me back the file was not choosen. But when i use first file chooser and second file upload button, all is ok....where is my problem?

```
<p:fileUpload value="#{MyBean.exampFile}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true" label="Choose file"
                                    update="#{id}_fileList @(.buttonPanelClass)" />

<p:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{MyBean.saveFile(rec, modCat)}" ajax="false"
                                    update="#{id}_fileList @(.buttonPanelClass)" icon="fa fa-arrow-up green"/>
```

This is a main part in outputpanel, which I add to page several times. Some idea? Thanks

EDIT:

```
<p:panelGrid columns="8" layout="grid"
    style="border:0px !important; background:none;"
    styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank"
    columnClasses="ui-grid-col-5, ui-grid-col-5">
    <p:inputTextarea placeholder="#{msg.medPro}" value="#{rec.product}"
        disabled="#{MyBean.z.locked}" rows="1">
        <p:ajax listener="#{MyBean.inv()}" update="@(.buttonPanelClass)"
            event="change" />
    </p:inputTextarea>
    <p:inputTextarea placeholder="#{msg.medProSco}" value="#{rec.sco}"
        disabled="#{MyBean.z.locked}" rows="1">
        <p:ajax listener="#{MyBean.inv()}" update="@(.buttonPanelClass)"
            event="change" />
    </p:inputTextarea>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{rec.mod}"
        disabled="#{MyBean.zos.locked}">
        <p:ajax listener="#{MyBean.inv()}" update="@(.buttonPanelClass)"
            event="change" />
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{rec.dPro}">
        <f:converter converterId="dProConverter" />
        <f:selectItems value="${MyBean.getDPro(id)}" var="dPro"
            itemLabel="#{dPro.name}" itemValue="#{dPro}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:fileUpload value="#{MyBean.modFile}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true"
        label="Choose file" />
    <p:commandButton value="Upload"
        action="#{MyBean.saveModFile(rec, modCat)}" ajax="false"
        icon="fa fa-arrow-up green" />
    <p:commandButton value="Download"
        actionListener="#{MyBean.downloadModFile(rec.modFileID)}" ajax="false"
        onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);"
        icon="fa fa-arrow-down white"
        disabled="#{not MyBean.isModeFileUpload()}">
        <p:fileDownload value="#{MyBean.modFileForDownload}" />
    </p:commandButton>
    <p:commandButton immediate="true"
        update="#{id}_medProList @(.buttonPanelClass)"
        action="#{MyBean.removeMedPro(medPro, rec)}" value="#{msg.remove}"
        disabled="#{MyBean.zos.locked}" />
</p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Please  make a [mcve]

Comment: And you **are** aware the `update`s are superfluous since you hava ajax=false and mode=simple

Comment: I make edit now.